# Geoviews Plots Displays Incorrect Longitude & Latitude / Displays Them in the Wrong Format

Tags: python, pandas, holoviz, geoviews

I have a Point with a `longitude = -0.050122` and `latitude = 52.699185`.

When I plot this in Geoviews, this Point is incorrectly displayed:

```py
pin = gv.Points(gdf_pin,vdims=["avg_cust_dist_trav_km","avg_cust_dist_trav_miles"]
                          ).opts(tools=["hover","tap"],
                                 color="green",size = 15,
                                 line_color="white",hover_color="orange",
                                 hover_line_color="white",line_width=2)
```

Output:

[image]

The same thing also seems to happen for Polygon plots produced using Geoviews as well.

Is this a bug or do I have to do something else to correctly display longitudes and latitudes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify, the point itself looks correctly displayed (plotted in the correct location), but the hover information is displayed in Web Mercator coordinates rather than the more human-readable native lat/lon values.  I believe this is a bug; see https://github.com/holoviz/geoviews/issues/470 .

(Not sure what the "th" in the hover is, though; I don't see that in my copy.)

Comment: @JamesABednar, you are correct in that it plots in the correct location but it is the displayed hover value that is incorrect. Thanks for the link to the bug. Yeah it was actually the "th" part that caught my eye - it is almost like it is ranking/ordering the Points or something

Comment: In my case I get the "th" too.

Comment: If you see the "th", please list your bokeh version, browser, and OS, so we can  try to reproduce that.